# How to pass Firebase data from table view cell to view controller?

Tags: swift, firebase

From now on, I have successfully fetch the data from the Firebase to the cell. However, the problem is that I cannot relate the data on the cell to the label on next view controller. More specifically, I want the label on the next ViewController to display my priceTextLabel in the PostTableViewCell and is that possible?

I am a very new programmer that I have seen similar cases but failed to apply those into my cases. Could someone please render me a helping hand?

Here is my Post class

```
import Foundation


class Post {

var form:String
var subject:String
var region:String
var price:String
var createdAt:Date
var gender:String

init(form:String, subject:String, region:String, price:String, gender:String, timestamp:Double) {
    self.form = form
    self.subject = subject
    self.region = region
    self.price = price
    self.gender = gender
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)
}
}
```

Then, I make the cell by creating a PostTableViewCell and its xib file.

```
import UIKit

class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {





override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

@IBOutlet weak var priceTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var formTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subjectTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var regionTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!



override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


func set(post:Post) {


    formTextLabel.text = post.form
    subjectTextLabel.text = "科目："+post.subject
    regionTextLabel.text = "地區："+post.region
    priceTextLabel.text = post.price
    subtitleLabel.text = post.createdAt.calenderTimeSinceNow()
}

}
```

And here is my view Controller code (including the table view cell):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class HomeViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {




var casetableView:UITableView!
var posts = [Post]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    casetableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    casetableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
    view.addSubview(casetableView)

    var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!


    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        layoutGuide = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    }
    casetableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: 414, height: 750)
    casetableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    casetableView.delegate = self
    casetableView.dataSource = self
    casetableView.reloadData()


    observePosts()




}

func observePosts() {

    let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    let queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: 20)

    _ = queryRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        var tempPosts = [Post]()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let form = dict["form"] as? String,
                let subject = dict["subject"] as? String,
                let region = dict["region"] as? String,
                let price = dict["price"] as? String,
                let gender = dict["gender"] as? String,
                let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double {


                let post = Post(form: form, subject: subject, region: region, price: price, gender: gender, timestamp: timestamp)
                tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
            }
        }

        self.posts = tempPosts
        self.casetableView.reloadData()

    })

}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CaseDetailsViewController") as? CaseDetailsViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

}



}
```

Lastly, here is my code on the next View Controller which includes a label but fail to display the data

```
import UIKit

class CaseDetailsViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var priceLbl: UILabel!


var pricess = ""



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    priceLbl.text = pricess

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `didSelectRowAt` you can set on your variable `pricess` the post attribute value.

It should look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CaseDetailsViewController") as? CaseDetailsViewController
    vc?.pricess = self.posts[indexPath.row].<#Attribute#>
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's exactly what I want !! Thanks